# Combining software and image licensing in the same repository

Tags: license-compatibility, license-recommendation, creative-commons, apache-2.0

I have a project under Apache license on GitHub. I want to add some non-text stuff into repository (logo).

1. Can I use Apache license for an image?
2. If not, what CC license is most 'aligned' with Apache license?
3. If I release source code under Apache, and image under some CC license, how should I write copyright file? Special clause? Two files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache license are not intended to be used for an image(logo)
Use this [**link**](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/) to find out the suitable license depending on your permissions.
I think it would be better if you could create a license file in the folder where the logo is saved and mention the copyright attribute in the **README.md** file that displays the logo and says,

 "**Logo licensed under CC-* License**"

Disclaimer: I'm just a programmer